# need to loop through an array of dynamic size php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a poker game where 2 to 5 players join the game before the start button is pressed.They are added to a players arrays array as objects containing userid and username.

I need to populate my currentUser with the player object then on a button click(call/raise/fold) move to the next in the array to give illusion of the game moving seat to seat

When the start button is clicked i set the current user to the first element in the array which works.

```
$thisPokergame->State['CurrentUser'] = RESET($thisPokergame->State['Players']);
```

then im trying this

```
    if($thisPokergame->State['CurrentUser'] == end($thisPokergame->State['Players']))
    {
        $thisPokergame->State['CurrentUser'] = reset($thisPokergame->State['Players']);
    }
    else{
        $thisPokergame->State['CurrentUser'] = next($thisPokergame->State['Players']);;
    }
```

the if works by itself e.g if its the last player in the array it set current user to the the first and so does the statement inside the else.

When i put them together i get currentuser as false and i cant see the reason. anyone have a solution or better way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you use a variable to keep tracking the current player position. you start with `$activePosition=0` for player1 then use `$currentUser = $thisPokergame->State['Players][$activePosition];` then when the player change you increment the counter `$counter = ++$counter/5;` if you have 5 players. Or maybe the position in your "State"is important?

Answer (score 1):

You are having this problem because the functions you're using move the internal array pointer.

You will always get `false` in the `else` part of your conditional, because when you use `end($thisPokergame->State['Players'])` in the `if` condition, you have moved the internal array pointer to the the last element. Then in the `else` when you do `next($thisPokergame->State['Players'])`, you get `false` because there are no more elements.

Without knowing for sure what is in `CurrentUser` or `Players` I'm not certain how this could be handled instead, but I think this might work:

```
$player = array_shift($thisPokergame->State['Players']);
$thisPokergame->State['Players'][] = $player;
$thisPokergame->State['CurrentUser'] = reset($thisPokergame->State['Players']);
```

Basically just rotate the first player in the list of players to the end of the list, and then set the current user to the new first player in the list.

Comment: yeah that makes perfect sense.is there any alternative way to do it?

Comment: @stephenreilly I just updated the answer with something I think could possibly work. It's untested on my end, though. Just my theory.

Comment: if i set a variable to current(array) can i then use next on that in the else?

Comment: I think the problem with that will be that the array will be initialized with its internal pointer set on its first element rather than a specific one within it, so you'd always just get the second element.